# I18nData::NoTranslationAvailable -- countries-DE-CH: Can't access Spree admin, general settings, edit

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

Not sure what I changed to get this error when clicking on the `Configuration` tab in the Spree Admin panel. The spree_i18n gem contains the DE-CH.yml file and I wasn't getting any problems before. Nor is this happening on any other page.

#### codesi18n_data (0.4.1) lib/i18n_data/file_data_provider.rb

```
DATA_SEPARATOR = ";;"
extend self
def codes(type, language_code)
  unless data = read_from_file(cache_file_for(type, language_code))
    raise NoTranslationAvailable, "#{type}-#{language_code}"
  end
  data
end
def write_cache(provider)
```

Error is raised here: **raise NoTranslationAvailable, "#{type}-#{language_code}"**

I'm using spree 2-2-stable and spree_i18n 2-2-stable gems.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [this issue](https://github.com/spree/spree_i18n/issues/404). This is the exact problem you are encountering.

Comment: Wow. Thanks! You just fixed the bug 2hrs ago :)